# Repeat a row based on column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df in pandas:

```py
df = { "id" : ["apple", "potato","lemon"],"som" : [4, 2, 7] , "value" : [1, 2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I would like to repeat each row based on `value`. Desired output is:

```py
results_df = {"id" : ["apple", "potato", "potato", "lemon", "lemon", "lemon", "lemon"] , "som" : [4, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7]}

results_df = pd.DataFrame(results_df)
```

How can I do this please?

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, try `df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['value'])).reset_index(drop=True).drop('value', axis=1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = { "id": ["apple", "potato", "lemon"], "som": [4, 2, 7], "value": [1, 2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
results_df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, df["value"])]
results_df = results_df.drop(columns=["value"]).reset_index(drop=True)
results_df
```

**Output:**

| index | id | som |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | apple | 4 |
| 1 | potato | 2 |
| 2 | potato | 2 |
| 3 | lemon | 7 |
| 4 | lemon | 7 |
| 5 | lemon | 7 |
| 6 | lemon | 7 |